# How to test website for larger displays?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to test my website in 1920px X 1200px and smart tv also.
But my screen resolution size is 1366px X 768px. I have already adjusted in mobile versions(small screens).
How can i test in larger displays in my machine?

Comment: You can test it with some online tool like [this one](http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Web page that you want to Test in Firefox/Chrome.

In **Mozila Firefox**, Use Responsive Design Mode by Pressing **Ctrl + Shift + M**,
and in **Google Chrome**, Use Toggle Device Mode by Pressing **Ctrl + Shift + M**.

Answer (score 3):

You can create iframe with specified size, and then set src to url you want to test.

```
<iframe style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px;" src="...."></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you can rightclick on the page -> inspect element(q) and then on the right-bottom side where all those little icons are is an icon labeled "test screen size".

Answer (score 0):

I just found this tool online, it has tons of presets that make it really handy. I was thinking about making something like this with the iframe, but then, here it is!

http://quirktools.com/screenfly